# Get part of lousy data

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I want to get part of large  data. some part of this data is as follows:

```
data = {{"(100)", -0.033716509`, -0.19824611`, 
    "(101)", -0.026845098`, -0.18296293`, 
    "(102)", -0.021913837`, -0.17231199`}, {"(103)", -0.015043555`,
-0.16745934`, "(104)", -0.0076064845`, -0.16494502`, 
    "(105)", -1.1449175`*^-15, -0.16417456`}, {"(106)", 
    0.0076064845`, -0.16494502`, "(107)", 0.015043555`, -0.16745934`, 
    "(108)", 0.021913837`, -0.17231199`}, {"(109)", 
    0.026845098`, -0.18296293`, "(110)", 0.033716509`, -0.19824611`, 
    "(111)", -0.054776429`, -0.23685639`}, {"(112)", -0.042058374`,
-0.20053958`, "(113)", -0.029721072`, -0.19132756`, 
    "(114)", -0.019094091`, -0.18620841`}, {"(115)", -0.0093881514`,
-0.18374386`, "(116)", -1.4016566`*^-15, -0.18296576`, "(117)", 
    0.0093881514`, -0.18374386`}, {"(118)", 
    0.019094091`, -0.18620841`, "(119)", 0.029721072`, -0.19132756`, 
    "(120)", 0.042058374`, -0.20053958`}, {"(121)", 
    0.054776429`, -0.23685639`, "("}, {}, {"ELE", "CENTROID", 
    "CARTESIAN", "STRESSES", "PRIN", "STRESSES", "PRIN", "STRAINS", 
    "PRINCIPAL", "STRAINS", "YM"}};
```

I want to get the elements starting from `"(111)"` to  `{}`.
I prefer not to use `Flatten` simply because I want the output to match the elements levels (but if Flatten is need that is ok).
the lists between `"(111)"` to  `{}` is a variable and can be more or less.
what is the best pattern that can take the elements from `"(111)"` to  `{}?`

**Note:**
This set of data is repeated multiple times in the large data list and I want them all.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting problem given the need to preserve structure.  The first idea that comes to mind:

```
pull[data_, s_, f_] := data /. {___, {___, s, a___}, b___, f, ___} :> {{s, a}, b, f}
```

Test:

```
pull[data, "(111)", {}]
```

> ```
> {{"(111)", -0.0547764, -0.236856}, {"(112)", -0.0420584, -0.20054, 
>   "(113)", -0.0297211, -0.191328, 
>   "(114)", -0.0190941, -0.186208}, {"(115)", -0.00938815, -0.183744, 
>   "(116)", -1.40166*10^-15, -0.182966, "(117)", 0.00938815, -0.183744}, {"(118)", 
>   0.0190941, -0.186208, "(119)", 0.0297211, -0.191328, "(120)", 
>   0.0420584, -0.20054}, {"(121)", 0.0547764, -0.236856, "("}, {}}
> ```

From your updated question I think you will want:

```
pullAll[data_, s_, f_] := 
  Cases[data, {___, {___, s, a___}, b___, f, ___} :> {{s, a}, b, f}, {0, -3}]
```

The *levelspec* `{0, -3}` will cover everything from the entire expression (as used here) to the deepest level at which it is possible for the pattern to match.  If you can narrow the range further it will likely improve performance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard can this answer be used in large data where same data above is repeated (the only difference is the numbers not the strings)? I am thinking to use this pattern with Cases.

Comment: @Algohi The only way to know is to try it an see. :^)  It should work if the data has the same structure, assuming I understand it.  What do you mean about using the pattern with `Cases`?

Comment: I mean some thing like this:                             `Cases[my large data, {___, { ___ , s_, a___}, b___, f_, ___} :> {{s, a}, b, f}]`

Comment: @Algohi Are you saying this pattern appears multiple times in your actual data?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes exactly you are correct. this pattern is repeated several times.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry I should have been more clear in my question. I have edit it and added this info.

Answer (score 1):

```
PullAll[data_, s_] :=
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[data, {___, s, a__} :> {s, a}]~Join~
  Most@DeleteCases[data, {a_ /; ToExpression@a < ToExpression@s, __}];

PullAll[data, "(116)"]
```

> {{"(116)", -1.40166*10^-15, -0.182966, "(117)", 
>     0.00938815, -0.183744}, {"(118)", 0.0190941, -0.186208, "(119)", 
>     0.0297211, -0.191328, "(120)", 0.0420584, -0.20054}, {"(121)", 
>     0.0547764, -0.236856, "("}, {}}